# グローバル変数をライブラリ関数を使って初期化する方法が知りたい

Tags: javascript

提示コードのコメント部内部のコードですがなぜグローバル変数をp5ライブラリの関数`color()`で初期化しようとすると下記のエラーが出て`constructor`で初期化するとエラーが出ないのでしょうか？そもそも出来ないのでしょうか？
参考サイトを参考にサンプルコードを入れて色々実験しましたが上手くいきません。

###### 参考サイト

https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup

###### Console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: color is not defined
    at Game.js:17:19
(anonymous) @ Game.js:17
Main.js:9 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Game is not defined
    at setup (Main.js:9:7)
    at p5._setup (p5.js:62985:27)
    at p5._start (p5.js:62908:25)
    at new p5 (p5.js:63261:22)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:62189:17)
```

###### Game.js

```js
const STAGE_WIDTH = 10;
const STAGE_HEIGHT = 23;

const STAGE_OFFSET_WIDTH = 200;
const STAGE_OFFSET_HEIGHT = 150;

const CELL = 30;
const DONW_SPEED = 5;

const START_POSITION_X = 3;
const START_POSITION_Y = 3;



let t;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const ColorCode = [
//      [0,0,0],          //背景
color(0,0,0),
      [255,255,255],    //壁

      [0,255,255],      //水色
      [255,255,0],      //黄色    
      [0,128,0],        //緑    
      [255,0,0],        //赤
      [0,0,166],        //ネイビー
      [255,166,0],      //オレンジ
      [128,0,128],      //紫      
];
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//ブロック
const Block = 
[
            [
                  [1,1,1,1],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

            [
                  [1,1,0,0],
                  [1,1,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

            [
                  [0,1,1,0],
                  [1,1,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

            [
                  [1,1,0,0],
                  [0,1,1,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

            [
                  [1,0,0,0],
                  [1,1,1,1],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

            [
                  [0,0,0,1],
                  [1,1,1,1],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

            [
                  [0,1,0,0],
                  [1,1,1,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
            ],

];

// ################################################################
// # stage クラス
// ################################################################
class Stage
{
      constructor()
      {
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          t = color(0,0,0);  
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //ステージ
            this.stage = 
            [
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
            ]
      }

      // ################################ ラインを削除 ################################ 
      // ################################ Update ################################ 
      Update()
      {
            
      }

      // ################################ Renderer ################################ 
      Renderer()
      {
            
      }

      
}
```

###### Main.js

```js
/////////////////
new p5();
/////////////////
let game =  new Game();;   //基底ループ

//初期化
function setup()
{
      createCanvas(1000,800); //キャンバスサイズ
      frameRate(60);
}

//描画
function draw()
{
      background(127);        //背景色

      game.Update();
      game.Renderer();


      frameRate(60);

}
```

###### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ja>
      <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Tetris</title>
            <body>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
                  
                  <script src=../p5/p5.js></script>


                  <!-- ユーティリティ -->
                  <script src=../Utility/Math.js></script>
                  <script src=../Utility/Vector.js></script>
                  <script src=../Utility/Collision.js></script>
                  

                  <script src="Script/Game.js" ></script>

                  <script src="Script/Main.js" ></script>
            </body>
      </head>
</html>
```

Comment: ここをよく読んでみるといいと思います。
https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup

ところで前回の問題は解決したのですか？

Comment: はい。解決しました。BAを押したのですが

Comment: 質問内容をまったく異なるものに変更するのはやめてください。コメントや回答が意味不明になります。  前の内容にロールバックしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setpu()`を読み出す前にp5の関数が使えない理由は下記に記載されています。

[Why can't I assign variables using p5 functions and variables before `setup()`?](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup)

上記に記載の通り、p5の関数はp5.jsのスクリプトを読み込んだだけでは有効になりません。次の段階を経る必要があります。

1. p5.jsのスクリプトを読み込みます。
2. HTMLページの読み込みが完了します。
3. p5が開始され、p5の関数がグローバルに使用できるようになります。

`setup()`は3.のp5開始後に読み出されるため、`step()`が読み込まれる時点ではp5の関数が使用できるようになっているという仕組みです。しかし、関数の外側の変数の初期化処理は、そのスクリプトが読み込まれた時点でされます。それは、3.の処理の前であるため、変数の初期化処理にp5の関数を使用できません。

解決策は二つです。

1. 関数の外側の変数の初期化は`setup()`内で行う。
2. スクリプトの最初にp5を手動で開始(`new p5();`を最初に追加)する。

最初のリンクにあった記事の最初のコードが1.の方法、次のコードが2.の方法になります。単純に、p5の関数が`setup()`の呼び出しに関わらず、使えるようにしたいという場合は、2.の方法を使うときでしょう。なお、2.の方法を使うと"p5.js seems to have been imported multiple times. Please remove the duplicate import"という警告が表示されますが、期待通りに動作するはずです。